# simultaneous writing to a file, in new lines

Tags: java, file

I am writing a line in a file if a certain condition is satisfied like this:

```
if (cond) {
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PATHTOFILE)));
...
```

but then also write to the same file (in a new line) if a certain other condition is satisfied like so :

```
...
else {
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PATHTOFILE, true)));
...
```

Now the problem is that when both of the conditions are quasi-simultaneously satisfied (two rapid clicks from the user, one leads to the first `if` and the second to the `else`), the else won't be executed and the second line won't be written to the file.

My question is how to enable the appending to a file without closing and reopening it through a FileWriter as I do.

Comment: This seems more like an issue with the UI design. You should only let the user choose one option or the other, not both at the same time. Let one action finish before letting the user start another one. As an aside, please never do `if (cond == true)` in Java; just do `if (cond)`.

Comment: The user finishes the first click and could click a second time, meanwhile the first writing to the file haven't finished for the second to be properly done: that's the issue, if the first and the second clicks are very fast, the writing of the second line doesn't occur

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: One option is to have one method that writes to the file.  The method can be called from as many places as necessary.

Comment: @Sam That's my point. Why do you let the user click multiple times before the task has finished? You could disable the button (or whatever) on the first click, and only reenable it when the task is finished. Or, if disabling-and-reenabling doesn't work for you, simply don't launch a second task if the first one hasn't finished. Or queue the tasks so they happen one after the other.

Comment: OK so how to queue the task of appending to a file in Java?

Comment: Well, if you have a UI then I assume you're offloading this work to a background thread. You could just use an `ExecutorService` with a single thread. If there's only one thread, then it can only execute one task at a time. But if this doesn't help solve your problem, then likely I'm misunderstanding something, and it would be best to [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: could you show us an example of ExecutorService in this case?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on `ExecutorService`](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) (and [another](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) and [another](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-executorservice)). Create one with a single thread (see `Executors` class), then just `submit` your tasks to it. The thread pool maintains a queue of tasks. And, again, if you create one with a single thread then only one task can be executed at a time. Make sure to `shutdown` the service when done with it, especially if you use non-daemon platform threads

Comment: Then i will have to submit to a single threaded ExecutorService each writing task (in the if, else), and it will take care of ordering the executions of these (the file writings), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the PrintWriter class does not throw any input/output exception. Instead, we need to use the checkError() method to find any error in it.

have you tried to read the checkError() in this case to see if you have something? if yes, in the else you can simply loop retrying until the checkError() is true.

Comment: If you are referring to this [checkError](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError()) method, then it returns `boolean` so what do you mean by _until the checkError() is blank_ ?